# GetMethodID find no id - android JNI

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I've a little problem with GetMethodID.

Java code (reduced):

```
package ch.geniali.Test.service;
public class Service extends Service {
    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Const.ACTION_INFO);
        intent.putExtra(Const.INTENT_MESSAGE, message);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

The JNI Method:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#define DEBUG_TAG "C_libG"

JavaVM* gJavaVM = NULL;
static JNIEnv *pEnv;
const char* kJavaClassPath = "ch/geniali/Test/service/Service";

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* pVm, void* reserved){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "Call JNI_OnLoad");

    gJavaVM = pVm;

    if((*pVm)->GetEnv(pVm, (void **)&pEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6)){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG,
                    "Failed to get the environment");
        return -1;
    }

    jclass gClass = (*pEnv)->FindClass(pEnv, kJavaClassPath);
    if (!gClass)
     {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG,"failed to get %s class reference", kJavaClassPath);
      return -1;
     }

    jmethodID mid = (*pEnv)->GetMethodID(pEnv, gClass, "sendMessage", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (mid == 0){
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG,"Method ID not found");
        return -1;
    }

    (*pEnv)->CallVoidMethod(pEnv, gClass, mid, "yay!!!");

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

gClass was found.. This is ok. But, jmethodID is not found. I do not know why.

logcat is no help for me.

03-21 20:46:07.059  16182-16182/ch.geniali.Test:Task D/C_libG Call JNI_OnLoad

03-21 20:46:07.059  16182-16182/ch.geniali.Test:Task W/dalvikvm? JNI WARNING: can't call Lch/geniali/Test/service/Service;.sendMessage on instance of Ljava/lang/Class; (CallVoidMethod)

03-21 20:46:07.059  16182-16182/ch.geniali.Test:Task W/dalvikvm? in Ljava/lang/Runtime;.nativeLoad:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (CallVoidMethod)

03-21 20:46:07.059  16182-16182/ch.geniali.Test:Task I/dalvikvm? "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE

Answer (score 1):

The method ID is found correctly, otherwise you would see the

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG,"Method ID not found");
```

message in your Android log.

Your error is that you are trying to invoke the `sendMessage()` method in on a `java.lang.Class` object, by doing

```
(*pEnv)->CallVoidMethod(pEnv, **gClass**, mid, "yay!!!");
```

The **gClass** is a Service.class reference, NOT a `Service` instance.

Comment: Uhh, that's correct.
03-21 22:02:14.906    2963-2963/ch.geniali.Test:Task D/C_libG﹕ Method ID 1836425304 found - yay!!

Comment: I do not understand.
The gClass is a Class object, NOT a Class instance. You need to invoke the sendMessage() method on a Service instance.

Comment: I'll try to make an example here. What you are doing right now is similar to `Service.sendMessage()`. But the `sendMessage()` method is NOT static, so you need a `Service` **instance**.

Comment: With my code, I can only call static methods?
Or how I can get the current instance of serivces?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to call a method on a Service, since a Service is not a standard Java object but acts as a remote object which is accessible via IPC calls only.

Comment: OK. I've an idea. I create a init method and set two variables. In the other methods I use this variables. Could that work?
static jobject gJobject;
static JNIEnv *pEnv;
void Java_ch_geniali_Test_service_Service_Init(JNIEnv * env, jobject this) {
 gJobject = this;
 pEnv = env;
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe access permission, could you change your "sendMessage" method's access label to public? Normally you cannot access private method using object.

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Const.ACTION_INFO);
        intent.putExtra(Const.INTENT_MESSAGE, message);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Comment: No, is the same.
Actually, I pull a C method in a long running task all 250ms. from java code. 
I resent that. I will call a Java method from a long running C task.

Comment: The JNI_OnLoad method implementation is only a test implementation.
Finally, i will use this code hier:
int *sendMessage(const char *message) {
 jclass gClass = (*pEnv)->FindClass(pEnv, kJavaClassPath);
 if (!gClass)
  {
   return -1;
  }
 
 jmethodID mid = (*pEnv)->GetMethodID(pEnv, gClass, "sendMessage", "(Ljava/lang/String)V");

 if (mid == 0){
     return -1;
 }
 (*pEnv)->CallVoidMethod(pEnv, gClass, mid, message);
 return 0;
}